# What is the string representation of numeric NULL in scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I need to map some values to Int in Spark Scala code. 
The problem is that null in my input CSV is represented as "NA".
I need to convert it to something that would be interpreted as Null.

What does not work:

```
replaceAll("NA", null).toInt
replaceAll("NA", "null").toInt
replaceAll("NA", "").toInt
replaceAll("NA", ".").toInt`
```

What works but is not a good solution:
    `replaceAll("NA", 0).toInt`

Any ideas what could be a good representation of NULL in such conversion?

Thanks, Michal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Simply Answer**: There is no `NULL` value for `Int` and `Long`, `Boolean` type. and only `Double` and `Float` has the `NaN` value for `NULL` value in **Scala**.

So there are 2 solutions for you scenario:

1.Use `Option` for your value, `NA` map to `None`, maybe like:

```
val myStr = "NA"
val result: Option[Int] = myStr match {
  case "NA" => None
  case i => Some(i.toInt)
}
```

2.Use `Double` to replace `Int` type for your **number**

```
val myStr = "NA"
val result: Double = myStr match {
  case "NA" => Double.NaN
  case i => Some(i.toDouble)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

CSV data source (`spark-csv` in Spark < 2.0, built-in data format in Spark >= 2.0) provides a `nullValue` option which can be used to specify the string representing `NULL` values. If data looks like this:

```
1,NA,2
NA,3,4
4,5,NA
```

you can read it:

```
spark
  .read.option("nullValue", "NA")
  .option("inferSchema", "true")  // Just for convenience 
  .csv(path)
```

with the result being:

```
+----+----+----+
| _c0| _c1| _c2|
+----+----+----+
|   1|null|   2|
|null|   3|   4|
|   4|   5|null|
+----+----+----+
```

You can also read data as strings and `cast`:

```
val df = spark.read.csv(path)

df.select(df.columns.map(col(_).cast("integer")): _*)
```

which should give the same result.